# How many times did Brock get rejected by women?

Tags: pokemon

On Bulbapedia's [article for EP068](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/w/index.php?title=EP068&oldid=2742876) "Make Room for Gloom", the Trivia section says this:

> Ash mentions that Brock will find plenty of more girls that will reject him. To be exact, Brock found over five hundred more girls that rejected him in his tenure in the anime.

Is this accurate? How many times did Brock get rejected by women over the course of the anime?

Comment: And yes, I realize that there are hundreds of episodes with Brock in them and that most of us don't have time to go through them. But apparently somebody claims to have done so to get an exact count, and I'm willing to be patient to know if they're right answer. I'll give as big of a bounty as I can if someone gives a satisfactory answer.

Comment: `$counter = 0; foreach($jennySis as $jenny){$counter += 1;} foreach($joySis as $joy){$counter += 1;}` that gets you probably 50% of them

Comment: "Rejected" is a fairly loaded term. There are times in which the woman will make her disinterest in Brock crystal clear; there are times when another character will simply pull his ear (or one of his Pokemon attack him) to get him to knock the flirting off. If we *don't* count any of the times in which he's had his ear pulled by Misty or Max, or when he was attacked by his own Pokemon, then the assumed number of times - practically every time he runs into Nurse Joy or Officer Jenny - can naturally come down quite a bit, since it's *rare* that either Misty or Max leaves this unchecked.

Comment: The trivia was added by [Skulblaka Shurtugal on 3 December 2010](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/w/index.php?title=EP068&diff=1273564&oldid=1241470). However, I didn't find it being disputed either on the [article's talk page](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Talk:EP068) or [author's talk page](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/User_talk:Skulblaka_Shurtugal). Unfortunately, I'm afraid the author has been [inactive since 2011](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Special:Contributions/Skulblaka_Shurtugal).

Comment: I don't think any woman on the face rejected brock.. it was May and other team mates who used pull him off holding his year.. I could be wrong

Comment: You'd need to be more specific on what rejecting means and if you count more than one rejection per girl. I don't think any of the girls ever outright told him "no". At least not in the Japanese version, which is the only one I am familiar with. Takeshis sweet talk is mostly just ignored.

Answer (score 2):

the answer is 0, why?

It is true brock proposed them but nobody was ever able to answer brock. whenever brock proposed someone, he got caught by his ear and being dragged away either by misty or of his own pokemon. I will not count it as rejection because the girl never said no.

there is some reference to my answer in this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MusaRI0TC_4

Comment: @Wondercricket check this video and see even once someone said no to brock? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MusaRI0TC_4

Answer (score 0):

By rejected I understand that you want to ask that how many times has it happened that Brock loved a girl but had to leave her. If this is your definition then Suzie and Professor Ivy and more girls will also be considered as even though they loved Brock at one point he had to leave them. Then the total **number of girls which rejected Brock are 697**. This counting is till the end of season 15.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Do you have a source to support the number of 697? Did you watch every episode and count each one? Did you read it somewhere? Did you give a random number?

Comment: @Wondercricket I watched every episode and counted each one by one. However this does not include the episodes which are banned in India Like The Soldier Porygon and The Legend of Dratini etc.